# FiveM Lua: How does AddReplaceTexture work

Tags: lua, fivem

How can i use AddReplaceTexture() to add a little image on the plate like in the picture below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know FiveM. I read the manual:

[AddReplaceTexture](https://docs.fivem.net/natives/?_0xA66F8F75)

> ```
> -- ADD_REPLACE_TEXTURE
> AddReplaceTexture(
>   origTxd --[[ string ]], 
>   origTxn --[[ string ]], 
>   newTxd --[[ string ]], 
>   newTxn --[[ string ]]
> )
> ```
>
> Experimental natives, please do not use in a live environment.

txd is a texture dictionary and txn is the textures name in that dictionary.

So for adding a new texture you'll have to create a texture dictionary, add the texture to a name and then use that to replace another texture name in another texture dictionary.

A texture dictionary can be created using CreateRuntimeTxd for example.

websearch yielded the following snippet that is supposed to work:

```
local txd = CreateRuntimeTxd('duiTxd')
local duiObj = CreateDui('http://i.imgur.com/bvhD7sq.gif', 640, 360)
_G.duiObj = duiObj
local dui = GetDuiHandle(duiObj)
local tx = CreateRuntimeTextureFromDuiHandle(txd, 'duiTex', dui)
AddReplaceTexture('mp_m_freemode_01_mp_m_stunt_01\\jbib_diff_005_a_uni',
    'uppr_diff_000_a_uni', 'duiTxd', 'duiTex')
```

Here a runtime texture dictionary is created. A texture is put into that dictionary. Then this is used to replace a texture that looks like it's part of the game.

Just research the functions used in that snipped in the documentation.